# CakePHP Auth->allow() not working

Tags: ajax, cakephp, authorization

I have an "autocomplete" search in my app that works fine for logged-in users.
Now I want to use it on the front page where the users are not yet logged in.

The beforeFilter of the controller looks like this:

```
    function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('search');

    if(isset($this->Security) && 
        $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() &&

        ($this->action == 'search' || $this->action == 'delete' || $this->action == 'index')) {
        $this->Security->validatePost = false;
        $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
    }
}
```

And the function like this:

```
public function search() {
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax() && ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))) 
        {
            $data = $this->CompaniesCollection->searchCompanies($this->request->data['term']);
            $this->set('data', $data);
            $this->render('/Ajax/response');
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a 403 (Forbidden) error when making the request.
Is the "Auth->allow('search')" not enough to let the function be used without login? Am I missing something?

Comment: put 'search' in array

Comment: Tried that, still the same 403 forbidden error

Comment: Is HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header set? That's what `isAjax()` calls checks for.